# How to use %LocalAppData% with git bash in Windows?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, git-bash

I want to automate my process of align and signing an APK (an app for Android). I use git bash as terminal inside VSCODE.

For this I am concatenating the commands I need into a shell script but I got a problem with the windows variables. Since the android SDK installs it self automatically on `C:\Users\myUserName\AppData\Local` I can access it using `%LocalAppData%` on CMD but not in bash because it throws:

```
$ %LocalAppData%
bash: fg: %LocalAppData%: no such job
```

Of course I would just write the complete path but it will make my script useless on my laptop and/or another machine that is not where I wrote the script.

Is there a way to access `%LocalAppData%` with git bash?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Is there a way to access `%LocalAppData%` with git bash?

Assuming git bash maps Windows environment variables to bash variables then you access them using `$VARIABLENAME`.

Cygwin bash example:

```
$ echo $LOCALAPPDATA
C:\Users\DavidPostill\AppData\Local
```

To list environment variables use `env`:

```
$ env
USERDOMAIN=Hal
OS=Windows_NT
COMMONPROGRAMFILES=C:\Program Files\Common Files
PROCESSOR_LEVEL=6
PSModulePath=C:\Program Files (x86)\PowerShell Community Extensions\Pscx3\;C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules
CommonProgramW6432=C:\Program Files\Common Files
CommonProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
FP_NO_HOST_CHECK=NO
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
TZ=Europe/London
HISTCONTROL=ignoredups,ignoredups
DISPLAY=:0.0
...
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Bash command line for Linux](http://ss64.com/bash/) -  An excellent reference for all things Bash command line related.
- [env](https://ss64.com/bash/env.html) - Display, set, or remove environment variables, Run a command in a modified environment.
- [shell variables](https://ss64.com/bash/syntax-variables.html) - You can use variables in bash as in any programming language. There are no data types so a variable can contain a number, or a string of characters.

Answer (score 0):

I would add that the useful utility "[cygpath](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/cygpath.html)" can be applied
**cygpath "$LOCALAPPDATA"** to get a cygwin friendly path to %LocalAppData%
( I realize you mention git bash, not cygwin, so this might not apply fully )